# Traffic flow Monitoring on a particular UDP Port

Tags: bash, shell-script

Is there any way from where we can monitor incoming traffic speed on a particular UDP port using bash?

There are tool like nload, vnstat which shows traffic flow on a particular interface.

Can someone please help me in this case? As I want to perform some bash actions according to the traffic flow on a particular port

Comment: iptables rules counters or ipset counters. You can get it's values from shell periodically

Answer (score 0):

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -w /tmp/xxx.pcap udp port xxx
```

will give you a pcap-file for port xxx.

If it is just trafic volumes, you can hack something like:

```
while : ; do 
    sudo timeout  5   tcpdump -i eth0 -s0 port 53 2> /dev/null | wc -l ; 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

For rate measurements, I recommand `pv` (from the `pv` package in Debian/Ubuntu). It can count lines and bytes.

For instance a basic tcpdump gives one line per packet, thus this would print the packet rate every 2 sec :

```
tcpdump -ni eth0 udp port 66 |pv -li2 >/dev/null
```

For the byte rate, ask `tcpdump` to output the raw packets and `pv` to count those bytes (its default mode) :

```
tcpdump -ni eth0 udp port 66 -w- |pv -i2 >/dev/null
```

However I'm not sure you can use it in a non-interactive way (like "sample for 10s then give me a measurement"). The closest I found is that kind of trick :

```
rate="$((timeout 11 tcpdump -ni eth0 udp port 66 -w- 2>/dev/null |pv -i10 -F%a -f >/dev/null) 2>&1)"
```